# Authentication problem: can't bypass the login prompt when browsing to the SQL Reporing Services website

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs

I'm having a hard time configuring Reporting services on one of our servers. I'm not uninitiated in the domain of IIS7 but I cannot get rid of the login prompt when I'm surfing to the Reporting services website.

What I did:

I made a windows and SQL user with the same name:

Then I choose Anonymous authentication in II7 and filled in the credentials of the specific R.S. user [IIS7_auth http://img32.imageshack.us/i/iis7auth.jpg](http://img32.imageshack.us/i/iis7auth.jpg) http://img32.imageshack.us/i/iis7auth.jpg/

I choose 'Local Service' as the service account in the R.S. configuration mgr http://img88.imageshack.us/i/rsconfigmgr.jpg/

The first problem is that there's always a pop-up when surfing to the website

The second is that when I'm able to log in I get the message that the user doesn't have the appropriate permissions.

The pop-up: http://img693.imageshack.us/i/loginpopup.jpg/

The server is a 2008 Web Server with SQL 2008 R2 Express.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Reporting Services doesn't use IIS for hosting the websites anymore.  You'll need to open IE in administrative mode and then browse to the site in order to view the UI.  Then you can give yourself and others rights to the SSRS application.

There is no way to remove authentication as authentication is required for reporting services.

Answer (score 0):

SQL 2008 RS doesn't use IIS. It puts a hook in http.sys.

When RS is first installed, only local administrator accounts have access. You need to login as a local admin, browse to the RS manager website (get the URL from RS configuration tool), and assign the user rights to RS.